# How to connect the LCD screen to the RaspBerry Pi 4B

Tags: lcd

Good morning, I have recently started my adventure with raspberry Pi, I am currently using raspberry pi 4B and I bought a DPI screen - LCD IPS 7 '' 1024x600px Waveshare 12885 and I do not know how to connect it to work: /

Comment: Welcome -- but English only please!

Answer (score 3):

Waveshare have a wiki that explains how to connect this to a Pi 4 in English at [this site here](https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/7inch_DPI_LCD).

Basically, fit the HAT and change config.txt to read:

```
[pi4]
# Enable DRM VC4 V3D driver on top of the dispmanx display stack
#dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d
max_framebuffers=2
dpi_timings=1024 0 0 0 88 600 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 60 0 26000000 6

[all]
#dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d
dtoverlay=dpi24
enable_dpi_lcd=1
display_default_lcd=1
dpi_group=2
dpi_mode=87
dpi_output_format=0x6f005
hdmi_cvt 1024 600 60 6 0 0 0
disable_overscan=1
```

Note it is important to comment out vc4-fkms-v3d (add the # at the start of the line).

Comment: Please don't include google translate stuff.  Post in English, if the OP or someone else need to translate if for themselves, they can do that, but we are English only.

Comment: Sorry - Just trying to be polite to a new user.

Comment: I know. This is one of the rules I like least to enforce, but I understand that if someone is allowed to do it, then anyone has to be allowed to do it, and then enforcing *any* kind of rule (re abusiveness, spam, quality, topicality, etc) becomes impossible on some scale.